# How to convert multiple values into singal array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
fieldData.OnData.bind( function(){
            fieldData.rows.forEach(function(row){
            
            console.log(row.qText)
        })
```

output

[image]

So my question is how do I get all these values into one array for use?

PS-(Basically I want last value moreover (2022-2023) )

Can anybody suggest a solution for this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `fieldData.rows[ fieldData.rows.length - 1 ].qText` this will give you the last value of the array

Answer (score 0):

I think it's already an array then you can use

```js
console.log(fieldData.rows) //array
```